# Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-UpsideDownCake

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, sdk

Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-UpsideDownCake

[image]

Comment: Please post sample code as text, not images.

Comment: And post especially the part where `android-UpsideDownCake` is set to be used. AFAIR this was the Android SDK name in early beta phase. Now it is simply `android-34`.

Comment: @Robert do you know how can i fix this error?

Comment: Search where `android-UpsideDownCake` or `UpsideDownCake` is used in your gradle config and replace it by `android-34` respectively `34`.